# Proper way to verify Realm is encrypting on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, realm

I've followed the [Encryption](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#encryption) documentation and [Sample Code](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift-2.2/Encryption/ViewController.swift).

I believe I have this setup correctly. (The Realm Browser crashes when I try to open my .realm)

What is the proper way to verify encryption?

Comment: If you're getting a crash the most useful thing you can provide us is the RealmSwift version and the Realm Browser version you're using. Additionally, any logs are useful as well.

Comment: It seems like the mac app had stopped updating at some point (it was still the old logo) deleting that and re-installing through the MAS fixed it. Thank you

Comment: Yup. I did this question because I know about some incompatibility errors with the old Realm Browser and the 2.0 versions of Realm Cocoa (and RealmSwift). What about the encryption? Did the Realm Browser asked you for the encryption key?

Comment: It did yes and I verified it only worked with the right key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify that a Realm file is encrypted by opening it via the Realm Browser's "Open Realm File" or "Open..." options. The Browser shouldn't crash when opening the file, but rather it should prompt with an alert asking if the Realm is encrypted, at which point you can enter the encryption key. You can verify that the file is encrypted with the appropriate key by confirming that specifying the right key successfully opens the Realm, while specifying any other value fails to open the Realm.

Comment: thanks. upgrading both realm and the mac app to the latest fixed this and I was able to follow what you said